# Any simple method to make an image unrecognizable?

Tags: python, image

I want to make an image unrecognizable *effeciently*.

I don't want to just make it completely black - I want people looking at this to be convinced that this is indeed a unique picture generated from a picture they have seen before.

I tried blurring an image 100 times but it's slow as hell and I was wondering whether there would be some nice method to do so.

I was just thinking whether it is possible to just "shuffle pixels" in python strictly for this purpose.

Please help

I have taken some suggestions from you guys, and I have written the following:

```
imageFile = "myfile.png"
im1 = Image.open(imageFile)
l = list( im1.tostring())
random.shuffle(l)
Image.fromstring('RGB', (100,100), ''.join(l) ).save('out.png')
```

EDIT: I pasted the code I wrote. It's pretty CPU intensive

Comment: How can the image both be unrecognizable and recognizable ("want people looking at this to be convinced that this is … from a picture they have seen before") at the same time?

Comment: Fred: If I tell you a friend of your sent you an invitation but then sent you a black image you know it's BS. However, if you know that this unrecognizable image (1:1 mapping preferred) then there's a good chance you will believe that it is someone you know.

Comment: If you send me something unrecognizable, then, by definition, I can't recognize it as an invitation.  Perhaps explaining your overall purpose would help.  I've interpreted your purpose as best I can in my answer, but it definitely is not a 1:1 mapping – it doesn't give a completely unrecognizable image either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just shuffle the order of the pixels? Depending on how recognizable you want it to be, you can do it for individual pixels, or break the image into blocks and just shuffle those.

Comment: As sahhhm said, the Python Imaging Library would work for this. If you check out the Image Module, you could get the pixels using list(im.getdata()), random.shuffle that list, then use putdata(). I'm not familiar with the library, so one of the modules might actually have a function that does it, but it seems pretty basic anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Take one pixel from a 3x3 block and replace the block with it.  Essentially you get a smaller image, though you don't have to resize it (which would make some images much too small to see).  This is related to blurring, but is much simpler/faster and results in a pixellated effect rather than an optical blur.

For example:

```
xxxxxx
xAxxBx
xxxxxx
xxxxxx
xCxxDx
xxxxxx
```

Becomes:

```
AAABBB
AAABBB
AAABBB
CCCDDD
CCCDDD
CCCDDD
```

Vary the block size as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a sequence of quick filters then. Blurring is CPU-intensive, so you go for inverting colours, switching pixel groups, flipping horizontally and/or vertically...

Answer (score 0):

For a simplistic approach, you can use [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to apply color transforms, image enhancements, point operations, and a variety of other options as shown in the [tutorial page](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm).